# Warning on altering columns in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I am running the following sql code in sybase

```
Declare @cp  int 
select @cp = count(*) from syscolumns  where id = object_id('activ') and name = 'pending'

if  (@cp = 0 )
begin

    execute("
       ALTER TABLE activ ADD pending        char(1)           DEFAULT  'Y'           
    ")
    print 'pending added '
end
```

When I run for the first time I get a "warning: The schema for table activ has changed. Drop and re-create each trigger on this table that uses the if update clause"

On subsequent runs I don't get this warning anymore. Is there any way to avoid getting this warning first time ?

Some helpful links I went through. [1](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36272.1600/doc/html/san1393050902708.html) [Information about the error itself](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00729.1500/html/errMessageAdvRes/BABHJEIH.htm). I still have no clue how to remove that error/warning.

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?)? what do you mean by 'subsequent runs' ... on subsequent runs did the column exist and therefore the `execute(...)` did not fire? ... did you drop the column between runs so that the `execute(...)` fires every time?

Comment: @markp its ASE. On subsequent runs it does not enter if condition because the alteration had completed first time. If I drop the column and run it again I will get same warning again.

Comment: so what you're saying is that the script behaves as expected ... when column doesn't exist the `execute(...)` is invoked and the warning message is generated ... when column already exists the `execute(...)` is **not** invoked so no warning message is generated; I'm not aware of any way to disable the warning message; can you (or your parent script) just ignore the message?